# Funky text styling above user flair

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, css

After every post there's the user info (name, rep, badges). This is what it looks like on Meta.SO:

> [image: My user flair on M.SO]

Here's what it looks like on TWP:

> [image: My user flair on TWP]

On MSO it is one consistent font size for both the type of action and the date. On TWP the timing is many points smaller than the type of action.

Perhaps it's minor, but shouldn't they both be the same size?

Comment: Could be related to one being an actual date and the other being a relative date. Either way, I think the smaller one looks better.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed. The change will be on live server after our next production build.